# Noise figure and bandwidth effect on signal jitter

Tags: jitter, lna

I have an SNSPD based photodetector which produces short electrical pulses. The pulses have very short rise time Tr and a longer fall time Tf (the picture actually shows it the other way round but this way it is easier to demonstrate the question). The fall time is not important in this case. I am interested in the rise time only.

The signal from the photodetector is  amplified by a low noise amplifier (LNA) with a gain G, noise figure NF[dB], and bandwidth BW. At the output of the LNA the signal is detected on the rising edge, at say 50% level (Vc.)

My understanding is that limited bandwidth will "flatten" the rise time and noise figure will add noise to the signal hence generating some noise at the 50% detection level, some uncertainty.

- How do I find the optimum or minimum bandwidth of the LNA that will not degrade the signal jitter?
- How can I calculate a graph showing jitter vs BW for a given gain and noise figure?

[image]

Comment: The faster the edge, or the narrower the pulse, the wider the bandwidth needed to process that edge (or pulse).

Comment: Are you only interested in pulse *timing*? Or is pulse *height* of interest too?

Comment: @glen_geek Pulses arrive randomly (ish). Typical rise time is 20-300ps (fall time is 100x longer, not important here). What should be the bandwidth of LNA to amplify these pulses without increasing the rise time and how that BW will affect jitter? The pulse height is also random to some extend. But lets say we can trigger at 50% of each pulse. I know that the noise figure has the largest impact on jitter, but I am not sure what the actual relationship is. I want to make a graph jitter vs. BW and jitter vs. NF. It is the calculation of jitter that I am mainly interested in.

Comment: Pulses are not periodic. There is a random length gap between the pulses, sometimes a second long.

Comment: We can use a constant fraction discriminator (CFD) to detect 50% height of each pulse.

Comment: The actual pulse can look like this: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/oltage-pulse-from-the-150-nm-wide-SNSPD_fig7_260268737

Comment: Using some rules-of-thumb for a square wave, a 20 ps edge (rise time) needs approximately 17.5 GHz of bandwidth.  You need more than that if higher fidelity is required.

Comment: @SteveSh I need  to show how to calculate that. And if I had say only 10GHz of BW, what impact would that have on jitter? I need to put a number on that.

Comment: If you choose a different amplifier with different BW, the NF is not likely to stay the same. The wider the BW, the more noise that will be admitted. You'd be better off just doing analysis/simulation with the different amplifiers that are available to you, and choose the one with the best results. (Also you might find it easier to work with input-referred noise as a spec than with NF)

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this, but it is taken from Dr. Eric Bogatin's rule of thumb #1 - **Bandwidth of a Signal from It's Risetime**.

First, I would use an idealized triangle wave for the analysis, with the rise & fall times equal to the fastest edge of your signal, (20 ps?).

Then compute the FFT of this idealized triangle waveform.  This will have frequencies components well above your fundamental.

Now start truncating the FFT by removing higher order terms (harmonics) and compute the IFFT of that spectrum.  This should give you a time domain representation of your (now) bandwidth limited signal.  Finally, see if this "distorted" signal meets you needs.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I find the optimum or minimum bandwidth of the LNA that will not degrade the signal jitter?

While SNSPDs are an exotic detector type, in terms of SNR and bandwidth, you can treat them similar to a photodiode or photomultiplier tube.  The same equations will apply:

[image]

Taken from this white paper:

https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=9817

For example, you mentioned 20 ps, so that would imply a bandwidth of 0.35/20 ps = 17.5 GHz.  This assumes a first order system, which may be a little different than the shape of your pulse, but should be close.

> How can I calculate a graph showing jitter vs BW for a given gain and noise figure?

This is a much harder question because it will depend intimately on the shape of your pulse, the algorithm you use to determine the arrival time of the pulse and the statistics of the noise.  I would not trust any rule of thumb or approximation to be particularly accurate here.

Instead, I would simulate it.  Record the shape of your pulse and then fit its centroid, peak or whatever you use.  That is your noiseless case.  Then add random noise to it, low pass filter it, and repeat many times.  From this you can build up a plot of your sensitivity to each term that precisely matches your specific situation.  You can also test the effect of different commercial amplifiers as well by plugging in their bandwidth, gain and noise factor into your simulation to see which will be best for your data.

Comment: I am aware of the Thorlabs white paper. The simulation is however tricky. I would have to add AC noise to a transient signal. There is not many simulators that can do that, and those that can, are expensive. Cadence Spectre is the most advanced simulator I have the licence for, but it is the basic licence without advanced features. I do not know how to setup such a simulation with commonly used simulators.

Comment: @Dictador This is a relatively simple thing to write in a normal programming language such as matlab or python.  You're essentially just adding a random number to a measurement you record then processing the data as you would normally.  I think using an external simulator to perform a generic task like this would not make sense if it were even possible.

Comment: In practice, I use wideband LNAs, but I do not care much about 3dB BW. I assume as BW the freq with gain higher than 5dB (min required for the signal to be detected in my system). Simulation would be very interesting but I do not know how to configure it. Experimenting with LNAs in real life is difficult as they have to be cooled down to 40 Kelvin.